# I am receiving an error "no clustertask found" when I check using the command "tkn clustertask ls" in tekton pipeline

Tags: operators, openshift, tekton

It seems I don't have the operators such as "buildah, git-clone"
How can I install them in openshift?

Answer (score 0):

When installing OpenShift Pipelines to an OKD/OCP cluster, the openshift-pipelines operator would deploy Tekton Pipelines, Triggers, ... stack to your cluster, alongside sample ClusterTasks.

While if we were to install a vanilla Tekton Pipelines, onto Kubernetes or Openshift, you would not find any ClusterTasks assets, unless installing them yourself.

To get buildah or git-clone ClusterTasks, you need to install the openshift-pipelines operator from OLM. That operator would keep those tasks up to date for you. OR, you would have to install and maintain them yourself, if you did choose to install vanilla tekton stack.

Sample Tasks / ClusterTasks could be found in [Tekton Catalog repository](https://github.com/tektoncd/catalog/tree/main/task)